# Вывести в консоль max кол-во комбинаций + и -

Tags: javascript

Есть 5 колонок, нужно сделать так, чтобы выводилось максимальное количество комбинаций + и - в строках. Например, + + + + +; + - - - -
и т.д. Максимум 32 комбинации.
Язык JS.
После лета давно не занимался и сложно придумать с чего начать. Подскажите, пожалуйста в какую сторону двигаться

Comment: если какой-то из ответов помог найти решение, отметьте его галочкой, чтобы люди в будущем могли воспользоваться этой информацией

Answer (score 1):

Представьте, что это двоичные числа, и перебирайте 00000, 00001,00010,00011,00100..., но при выводе 0 меняйте на -,а 1 на +

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать формулу из комбинаторики. Например, у вас длина строки 3, тогда: 2 возвести в степень 3. 2 - это количество знаков, в нашем случае: + и -. 3 - длина строки. Если длина строки 5, то максимально количество комбинаций будет: 2^5=32.